# RequireJS adding .js to localhost:8020/signalr/hubs

Tags: .net, path, requirejs, signalr

I currently have a .Net SignalR server and a JS SignalR client using RequireJS.

In my main.js I have the following path:
`'hubs': 'http://localhost:8020/signalr/hubs'`

However, RequireJS automaticaly adds a `.js` to the end of that path, and then it returns a 404 error because that url is not found.

How do I prevent RequireJS of adding an extension to that URL?